# Dynamic function calling in Java 8 Streams

Tags: java, java-8

```
List<?> temp = empObjList.stream()
                    .filter(nestedDo -> nestedDo.getAttrib1() == "subject")
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Here I'm calling the method getAttrib1(). But The method to be called is identified only dynamically. I will get only the name of the function as a String value. I want to convert it dynamically to function. I know I can use Reflections for the dynamic method calling, but I can't rewrite the above code by reflection.

Comment: Hey don't you think u need to change `=="subject"` to `.equals("subject")`?

Comment: If "subject" is a name of a function, there is no way to do it without reflection.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly your goal is, but I am really sure there is a much better way to do this than passing method names as strings and then using reflection. How about you show us the bigger picture?

Comment: @Philipp: I want to filter a set of objects based on the conditions. Here getAttrib1() is the  function to be called if I want to check the condition on field attrib1. Selection of field is done dynamically.

Comment: @DeepakShajan You could implement a [Predicate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) object for each possible field.

Comment: @Philipp: I don't know nothing about predicate object. Can you explain it further.

Comment: @DeepakShajan It's the functional interface you pass to `stream.filter`. What do you want to know about it? When your question is more complex than can be answered with more than one sentence, please create a new question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is something more like

```
List<?> temp = empObjList.stream().filter(this::processDo)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Where `processDo(nestedDo)` is a method that does the reflection to figure out what method to call on the do.

Comment: can u write the code of method processDo that does reflection.

Comment: There are tons of examples on how to get methods by name using reflection.  Just google it or search here.

Comment: Sorry @MadConan I still didn't get a way to write the code of this method.